# Executing keras aborts RStudio session

Tags: keras, rstudio

I am trying to install keras in a laptop with R and RStudio previously installed.

I first installed Anaconda3 following the instructions here https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/.

Second, I followed these instructions to install keras and tensorflow in RStudio https://github.com/FrancisArgnR/Guide-Keras-R (cpu instructions), but specifying conda method:

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
library(keras)
install_keras(method = c("conda"))
```

However, whenever I tried to run keras functions (`data <- dataset_mnist()`), RStudio session aborts. When I use R in the terminal I get the error:

```
> library(keras)
> data<-dataset_mnist()

 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7fb3e50fe820, cause 'illegal operand'

Traceback:
 1: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
 2: import(module)
 3: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 6: tryCatch(import(module), error = clear_error_handler())
 7: py_resolve_module_proxy(x)
 8: `$.python.builtin.module`(keras, "datasets")
 9: keras$datasets
10: dataset_mnist()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

I found a similar error previously reported here https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/228, although the "Traceback" is not exactly the same. I tried specifying an earlier version of Tensorflow as suggested, but the error perstists.

```
install_keras(method = c("conda"),tensorflow = "1.5")
```

I tired serveral tensorflow versions, from 1.9 to 1.0, but I obtain the same behaviour.
I also tried installing keras from CRAN with `install.packages("keras")` and repeating all the procedure, but nothing changed. If I do not specify the conda method, the same happens, but in addition, I obtain the following errors when running `install_keras()`:

```
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 requires pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 requires typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 has requirement six==1.12, but you'll have six 1.13.0 which is incompatible.
```

Some details in case they can be useful:

R version 3.6.1, Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

RStudio: Version 1.2.5019

OS: Ubuntu 19.10

Processor: Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N3450 @ 1.10GHz × 4

5,6 GiB RAM

Comment: Not an answer yet, but my Ubuntu crash messages had a node labelled "UnreportableReason," which said, "You have some obsolete package versions installed. It listed many and suggested upgrading, which I did with `sudo apt-get upgrade`. RStudio still crashed, but that node in the report now said "This is not an official Ubuntu package." The other error messages appeared to refer to Miniconda. The next thing I'll try is installing Anaconda myself before installing keras, instead of allowing the keras installation to add Miniconda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your problem is caused by the **lack of AVX instructions support of your CPU**.

First you should know that when you run `install_keras(method = "conda")` a new environment (usually named `r-tensorflow`) is created. All the Python libraries required to run Tensorflow within R will be installed in this environment. When you run Keras code in R what R does is call the Tensorflow library of this environment.

Most of the pre-built binaries of Tensorflow are compiled on a CPU supporting the AVX instructions set given that this instructions allow a drastic speed up in certain floating point operations. Intel started to support these instructions in 2011. Although your CPU seems to be produced in 2016 it is a Celeron and as we can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions):

*Not all CPUs from the listed families support AVX. Generally, CPUs with the commercial denomination "Core i3/i5/i7" support them, whereas "Pentium" and "Celeron" CPUs don't.*

You can check this by running on your linux terminal `lscpu | grep avx`. If nothing is shown your CPU does not support these instructions.

Under these circumstances you have two options:

- Build Tensorflow from source in order to compile the code given your CPU features. You can find more info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)
- Find a pre-built binary of Tensorflow built for CPU without AVX support. Something like [this](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues/103)